# How to install Apache2 on linux

Tags: installation, apache2

I tried more option to install Apache2 on my Ubuntu os but i got error like

dpkg: error processing package php5-mysql (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of phpmyadmin:
 phpmyadmin depends on php5-mysql | php5-mysqli | php5-mysqlnd; however:
  Package php5-mysql is not configured yet.
  Package php5-mysqli is not installed.
  Package php5-mysqlnd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5) ...No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Enabling module mpm_event.
Enabling module authz_core.
Enabling module authz_host.
Enabling module authn_core.
Enabling module auth_basic.
Enabling module access_compat.
Enabling module authn_file.
Enabling module authz_user.
Enabling module alias.
Enabling module dir.
Enabling module autoindex.
Enabling module env.
Enabling module mime.
Enabling module negotiation.
Enabling module setenvif.
Enabling module filter.
Enabling module deflate.
Enabling module status.
Enabling conf charset.
Enabling conf localized-error-pages.
Enabling conf other-vhosts-access-log.
Enabling conf security.
Enabling conf serve-cgi-bin.
Enabling site 000-default.
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php5-mysql
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

and sometime i got error E: Unable to locate package libmysqlclient15off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in linux terminal do

1. install apache2

   `sudo apt-get update`

   `sudo apt-get install apache2`
2. install mysql

   `sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql`

hope this helps sir